# 'Google Play Services' cannot be used, please try to allow permission error after adding Bundled MLKit Scanning in Non GSM mobile

Tags: java, android, google-play-services, scanning, google-mlkit

I am getting this error '**'Google Play Services' cannot be used, please try to allow permission**' after I have added Bundled MLScanning Kit to app.
I am using a mobile without google play services.
This message comes with alert dialog randomly whenever app is installed in that device.

[image]

Comment: Can you share on which packages you have declared a dependency? For bundled packages this indeed should not happen.

Comment: Can you also provide the device you use, is it might related to https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Moto-M/How-to-give-permissions-to-Settings-app-on-Moto-M/m-p/3660709?

Comment: @Chrisito added this line in dependency

implementation 'com.google.mlkit:barcode-scanning:16.1.1'

Comment: @Chandankushwaha Thanks, that's helpful, can you also indicate which phone/device you are running this on and on which build of Android it is? Thanks!